# Compiling Issue with Margins

Tags: margins, miktex, compiling, texstudio

I have run into an issue where different computers are compiling files differently. On my desktop computer, everything compiles like normal, but on my new laptop the bottom margin is getting sliced off. I use TeXstudio and MiKTeX on both computers, and I have double-checked that both computers are set to use standard letter sized paper within MiKTeX, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

I'm really at a loss here, I have never experienced this issue before. Thanks for any help you might be able to supply!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[
top    = 1.00in,
bottom = 0.50in,
left   = 0.75in,
right  = 0.75in,
headsep= 0.15in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{MTH 2410}
\chead{Summary of Tests for Series}
\rhead{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
{
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{C{2.9cm} C{2.6cm} C{3.46cm} C{3.2cm} L{3.5cm}}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Series or Test} & \textbf{Form of Series} & \textbf{Condition(s) for Convergence} & \textbf{Condition(s) for Divergence} & \textbf{Comments} \\
            \midrule
            Geometric Series & $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} ar^k$, $a\ne 0$ \newline[1mm] $N=0,1,2,\dots$ & $|r|<1$ & $|r|\geq 1$ & If $|r|<1$, then the \newline[1mm] sum is $S=\frac{ar^N}{1-r}$. \\
            \midrule
            Telescoping Series & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\big(b_k - b_{k+1}\big)$ & $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n = L$, where \newline[1mm] $-\infty<L<\infty$ & $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n$ DNE & Trick: Write out $S_n$, cancel terms, then evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$. \\
            \midrule
            Divergence & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ & This test \underline{\textbf{CANNOT}} be used to show convergence! & $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k \ne 0$ & Test is \textbf{inconclusive} if $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k=0$. \\
            \midrule
            Integral ($f$ is continuous, positive, and decreasing) & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$, where \newline[1mm] $0<a_k=f(k)$ & $\int_1^{\infty}\! f(x)\, dx$ converges \newline[2mm] The series does \underline{\textbf{NOT}} converge to this value. & $\int_1^{\infty}\! f(x)\, dx$ diverges & Remainder satisfies \newline[1mm] $|R_n| \leq \int_n^{\infty}\! f(x)\, dx$ \\
            \midrule
            $p$-Series & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^p}$ & $p>1$ & $p\leq 1$ & Useful for comparison tests. \\
            \midrule
            Ratio & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ & $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|<1$ & $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|>1$ & Test is \textbf{inconclusive} \newline[1mm] if $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=1$. \\
            \midrule
            Root & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ & $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} < 1$ & $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} > 1$ & Test is \textbf{inconclusive} \newline[1mm] if $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} = 1$. \\
            \midrule
            Direct Comparison ($a_k,b_k>0$) & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ & $0<a_k\leq b_k$ and \newline[1mm] $\textstyle\Sigma b_k$ converges. & $0<b_k\leq a_k$ and \newline[1mm] $\textstyle\Sigma b_k$ diverges. & $\textstyle \Sigma a_k$ is given; you supply $\textstyle \Sigma b_k$. \newline[1mm] The ``work'' is showing the inequality. \\
            \midrule
            Limit Comparison ($a_k,b_k>0$) & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ & $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k} = L$, \newline[1mm] $0\leq L<\infty$, and \newline[1mm] $\textstyle\Sigma b_k$ converges. & $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k} = L$, \newline[1mm] $0<L\leq\infty$, and \newline[1mm] $\textstyle\Sigma b_k$ diverges. & $\textstyle \Sigma a_k$ is given; you supply $\textstyle \Sigma b_k$. \\
            \midrule
            Alternating \newline Series & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}a_k$, \newline[1mm] where $a_k> 0$ & $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$ and \newline[1mm] $0<a_{k+1}\leq a_k$ & $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k \ne 0$ & Remainder satisfies \newline[1mm] $|R_n|\leq a_{n+1}$ \\
            \midrule
            Absolute Convergence & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|$ converges & n/a & If $\textstyle \Sigma |a_k|$ diverges, $\textstyle \Sigma a_k$ may be conditionally convergent. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\underline{\textbf{Properties of Convergent Series}}\\[2mm]
Suppose that $\textstyle \sum a_k$ and $\textstyle \sum b_k$ converge to $A$ and $B$, respectively, and let $c$ be any real number.
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \item The series $\textstyle \sum ca_k$ converges and $\textstyle \sum ca_k = c \sum a_k = cA$.
    
    \item The series $\textstyle \sum (a_k \pm b_k)$ converges and $\textstyle \sum (a_k \pm b_k) = \sum a_k \pm \sum b_k = A \pm B$.
    
    \item \textit{Whether} a series converges does not depend on a finite number of terms added to or removed from the series. However, the \textit{value} of a convergent series does change if nonzero terms are added or deleted.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: impossible to say anything given the information provided, show a small one page document that isn't giving the margins you expect and someone could debug

Comment: Sorry, I had to wait until I got home to do some testing. Do you mean the code or the screenshots of the different margins?

Comment: Show code that others can copy and test as is

Comment: Edited my post with the file where I noticed this behavior. On one computer, it properly makes a one page PDF, but on the other computer it throws the third item in the enumerate to the next page.

Comment: the posted code is missing `\end{document}` but if I add that I get two pages, the last just having the third item. add `\listfiles` to your document show it shows package versions in the log and compare the lists on your system that gives a single page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did as you suggested and the log just says the following:

2021-08-16 19:41:26,466-0600 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MTH 2410 Summary of Tests for Series.tex"
2021-08-16 19:41:26,471-0600 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-08-16 19:41:26,471-0600 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2021-08-16 19:41:26,698-0600 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 0

Comment: I should add that the above log was from the computer which outputs the 1 page PDF.

Comment: So now that I have re-read your suggestion, I took a look at the log file for the computer that outputs the extra page. Most of it looks the same, but it does have a couple of extra lines:

2021-08-17 15:04:55,377-0600 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.8.0 (1.40.23) (MiKTeX 21.8)

the above line shows up twice. I have updated all the packages on both computers via the update tool, but the issue still persists. While I was at my office today, I ran the file on my work computer and it also only prints one page. I'm so flabbergasted!

Comment: I think I might have solved my own problem. Even though the packages were up to date on all the computers, I uninstalled Miktex from the PC that was printing it to one page, and reinstalled it. It now prints to two pages, so at least now everything is consistent!